# couldn't find Object with id=

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to add a column to a table that displays all the products in my active record that will allow me to remove a product for a given row. When I try to run the code I get an error that matched the title.

**Products Controller**

```
def destroy
@product = Product.find(params[:id])
@product.destroy
redirect_to :back
end

private

def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:ta_code, :tatr, :oem, :name, :kind, :ta_type, :id)
end
```

**Delete Button section of code**

```
<% Product.all.each do |product| %>
      <% if product.kind == "oem" %>
      <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#all<%= product.tatr %>" class="accordion-toggle">
        <% if can? :destroy, Product %> 
          <td><%= button_to "delete", delete_path(@product), :method => :delete %></td>
        <% end %> 
        <td><%= product.id %></td>
        <td><%= product.tatr %></td>
        <td><%= product.name %></td>
        <td><%= product.oem %></td>
        <td><%= product.created_at.strftime("%b/%d/%y") %></td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
```

**Routes.rb**

```
get 'signup' => 'users#new'
root 'static#home'
get 'systems' => 'static#pages'
get 'help' => 'static#help'
get 'ce' => 'static#ce'
get 'oem' => 'static#oem'
get 'update_existing' => 'static#update_existing'
get 'reports' => 'static#reports'
get 'miscellaneous' => 'static#miscellaneous'
get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
get 'create_new' => 'products#new'
delete 'delete'=> 'products#destroy'
get 'new_status' => 'microposts#new'
get 'list' => 'users#list'
resources :users
resources :products
resources :microposts
```

This is my first real project so I'm sure the convention is a little off and organization may be lacking, but that comes with time. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
delete_path(@product)
```

with

```
delete_path(product)
```

Comment: No affect unfortunately.

Comment: Why are explicitly creating a path for deleting the product when it is automatically generated by rails?

Comment: My initial problem was not having a correct route something about [delete]/oem. I worked through that problem and wound up with the route `delete 'delete' => products#destroy' is my bigger problem in my route?

Comment: Is oem a column of the products table or an association?

Comment: oem is the the name of the view page that is rendering all this as well as a parameter for my Product model that is being displayed in the table.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing an object instead of it's id here:

```
<% if can? :destroy, Product %>
   <td><%= button_to "delete", delete_path(:id => product), :method => :delete %></td>
<% end %>
```

It should be `delete_path(product)` or `delete_path(id: product.id)`

Comment: I changed it to what you recommended,but the error remains the same. The error is in `@product = Product.find(params[:id])`

Comment: Could you please show `params.inspect` on the action?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar and don't know how. Are you talking about on the destroy action and as a command prompt?

Comment: In your controller's destroy method just write `raise params.inspect` and do what you did before. It should raise you the contents of params.

Comment: {"_method"=>"delete", "authenticity_token"=>"r10wVqOBS85dyACpTXu/vdnK7IVziI81fOvqtjQHS+r7UviXHzbjd4ALsHmovm5/QWwPwXJIFyo3bR5bJOzwPQ==", "controller"=>"products", "action"=>"destroy"}

Comment: Darpa has a good point in his answer, it should be product, not @product. Updated my answer.

Comment: I tried that, but still no progress. Can I ask why? is it because that's how its labeled in my do?

Comment: Yes, you're passing product, not @product via your `.each`.

Comment: Thank you. The problem has been resolved. You were very helpful.